# Quick bash script to run a script in a specified folder?

Tags: bash, ubuntu

I am attempting to write a bash script that changes directory and then runs an existing script in the new working directory.

This is what I have so far:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /path/to/a/folder
./scriptname
```

scriptname is an executable file that exists in /path/to/a/folder - and (needless to say), I do have permission to run that script.

However, when I run this mind numbingly simple script (above), I get the response:

**scriptname: No such file or directory**

What am I missing?! the commands work as expected when entered at the CLI, so I am at a loss to explain the error message. How do I fix this?

Comment: Hmm, judging by the many (varied) responses - including one or two that must surely be overkill - I can't help but wonder - surely there must be a simple way of chaging into a folder and running a script in that folder?

Comment: You have not copied the script to that folder. ./scriptname means the script is in that folder, which is not the case. Invoke the script by giving the correct path.

Comment: Could you add the following as an alias for what you want? "bash /path/to/script/script.sh"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
cd /path/to/a/folder
pwd
ls
./scriptname
```

which'll show you what it thinks it's doing.

Comment: I am already doing that (granted I did not show that in my OP - to keep things simple). pwd indicates that the cd worked and ls shows that the file is there - hence my bewilderment at the error message I am getting

Comment: I'll accept this is as the closest answer. I was using auto competion at the CLI - so I did not enter the .sh extension. Whereas, in the script, I have to use the full file name

Comment: Oh, you definitely need the full file name.

Answer (score 4):

Looking at your script makes me think that the script you want to launch a script which is locate in the initial directory. Since you change you directory before executing it won't work.

I suggest the following modified script:

```
#!/bin/bash
SCRIPT_DIR=$PWD
cd /path/to/a/folder
$SCRIPT_DIR/scriptname
```

Comment: No, you must have misunderstood me. I want to run scripts in /path/to/a/folder (thats why I 'cd /path/to/a/folder' first).

Comment: Ok I understand. I suppose everything is ok when you run it by hand. My only suggestion so far would be to add the `-xv` options to you `#!` line and check what's printed.

Answer (score 1):

I usually have something like this in my useful script directory:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Provide usage information if not arguments were supplied
if [[ "$#" -le 0 ]]; then
        echo "Usage: $0 <executable> [<argument>...]" >&2

        exit 1
fi

# Get the executable by removing the last slash and anything before it
X="${1##*/}"

# Get the directory by removing the executable name
D="${1%$X}"

# Check if the directory exists
if [[ -d "$D" ]]; then
        # If it does, cd into it
        cd "$D"
else
        if [[ "$D" ]]; then
                # Complain if a directory was specified, but does not exist
                echo "Directory '$D' does not exist" >&2

                exit 1
        fi
fi

# Check if the executable is, well, executable
if [[ -x "$X" ]]; then
        # Run the executable in its directory with the supplied arguments
        exec ./"$X" "${@:2}"
else
        # Complain if the executable is not a valid
        echo "Executable '$X' does not exist in '$D'" >&2

        exit 1
fi
```

Usage:

```
$ cdexec
Usage: /home/archon/bin/cdexec <executable> [<argument>...]
$ cdexec /bin/ls ls
ls
$ cdexec /bin/xxx/ls ls
Directory '/bin/xxx/' does not exist
$ cdexec /ls ls
Executable 'ls' does not exist in '/'
```

Comment: Erm, some comments in the script would be nice - at the moment, it just looks like Perl (i.e. gobbledygook) to me ..

Comment: @skyeagle: I added some comments and a usage example

Comment: @thkala: how to rewrite whis script as a function?

Answer (score 0):

One source of such error messages under those conditions is a broken symlink.

However, you say the script works when run from the command line. I would also check to see whether the directory is a symlink that's doing something other than what you expect.

Does it work if you call it in your script with the full path instead of using cd?

```
#!/bin/bash
/path/to/a/folder/scriptname
```

What about when called that way from the command line?